# Remove and add view without losing its properties in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom view in which I am adding an image showing some data about that image. When I click on that I remove that custom view from its parent and add it to DailogFragment. But after adding that view in DailogFragment, the custom view lost the data related to the image. Is there any way to preserve that custom view. I don't want to store that data anywhere else.

Comment: Can you share your code here.

Comment: You can make use of constructor, or static, or shared prefs etc.

Comment: don't want to save data out of view.

Answer (score -1):

try sharedprefrence. It stores data in the phone cache memory